# Check if my ssd is SATA or M2

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, m2

I have a PC with two ssd slots, SATA3 and M2, and I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.
Right now I have only one ssd, and I would like to bought a second one.

I don't know if actually there is a SATA or a M2 hard disk. How can I check it, without disassembly the pc?

Comment: does this resource help answer yor question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65595/how-to-know-if-a-disk-is-an-ssd-or-an-hdd

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable opening the PC now just to have  a look, (so your aren't pulling wires yet) how are you going to install the purchased SSD?

Comment: Because it's a laptop and the screw are very small, there is a risk to ruin them, so the fewer times I open it, the better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Disks, it will tell you the drive model which you can then look up on the internet